# Count the number of occurrences of one vector entirely in another vector

Tags: c++, loops, recursion, vector

I am writing a simple function that returns an integer indicating the number of times the
contents of one vector appear in another.

For Example:

```
    vector<int> v1 {1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 9, 1, 4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 2};
    vector<int> v2 {1, 4, 2};

    cout << countOccurrences(v1, v2);
```

Should return 4.

> Here is my iterative solution

```
int countOccurrences(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2) {
    int i, j, count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= v1.size() - v2.size(); ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < v2.size(); ++j) {
            if(v1[i + j] != v2[j])
                break;
        }
        if(j == v2.size())
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I want to write the same function recursively but I am clueless. I am new to recursion and It seems intimidating to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (in pseudo code):

```
int countOccurrences(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2) {
    if v1 is shorter than v2
        return 0;
    if v1 starts with v2
        return 1 + countOccurrences( v1[1:], v2 )
    else
        return countOccurrences( v1[1:], v2 );
}
```

Comment: It is way easier to write in Python because of slicing. But we don't really have slicing and `startwith()` in C++?

Comment: @Sherlock `startwith()` shouldn't be that hard: `std::equal(v1.begin(), std::next(v1.begin(), v2.size()), v2.begin())` would be one way to check if `v1` starts with `v2` in C++11 - C++17.

Comment: @Sherlock C++20 has [starts_with](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with)

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a bit easier if you use iterators:

```
template <typename IT>
int count_occurences(IT begin,IT end,IT s_begin,IT s_end) {
    auto it = std::search(begin,end,s_begin,s_end);
    auto dist = std::distance(s_begin,s_end);
    if (it == end) return 0;
    return 1 + count_occurences(it+dist,end,s_begin,s_end);
}
```

`std::search` searches for one range, `[s_begin,s_end)`, inside another range, `[begin,end)`. I suppose you do not want to use it, so I leave it to you to replace it with your handwritten way to find one inside the other. The recursion comes into play by accumulating `1` when the sequence was found and call the function again only for the remainder of the vector.

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/6PcY5P)

Answer (score 1):

yet, a c++ 20 solution :

```
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <algorithm>

int countOccurrences(std::span<int> data, std::span<int> needle)
{
    if (data.size() < needle.size())
        return 0;

    if (std::equal(needle.begin(), needle.end(), data.begin()))
        return 1 + countOccurrences(data.subspan(1), needle);
    else
        return countOccurrences(data.subspan(1), needle);
}


int main()
{

    std::vector<int> data{ 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 9, 1, 4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 2 };
    std::vector<int> needle{ 1, 4, 2 };

    printf_s("%d\n", countOccurrences(data, needle));
}
```

this is much faster than using sub vectors each recursion because it is only a view ! no allocation !

Comment: You could also use `ranges::equal` [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/osz9h8).

Comment: @cigien yes, but it isn't yet available in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on the pseudo-code provided by Scott Hunter.

```
bool start_with(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2) {
    for(auto i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i)
        if (v1[i] != v2[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
int countOccurrences(vector<int> &v1, vector<int> &v2) {
    static int i = 0;
    if(v1.size() < v2.size()) {
        return 0;
    }

    else if(start_with(v1, v2)) {
        vector<int> temp(v1.begin() + i + 1, v1.end());
        return 1 + countOccurrences(temp, v2);
    }

    vector<int> temp(v1.begin() + i + 1, v1.end());
    return countOccurrences(temp, v2);
}
```

### Feel free to suggest an alternative to the lazy hack i.e. `static variable` that does not change the function prototype.

Comment: This is wasteful in terms of having to create a vector each time you check for the next occurrence.  A better recursive method would have the base function take a vector, and recursive helper functions that take indices or even a pointer to the starting position in the vector to find the next occurance.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie see my answer for a faster one